# Dynamic Space between Elements in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML Code:

```html
<label>Title</label>
<input><br>
<label>Description</label>
<input>
```

The page then looks like this:

Title:  _______
Description: _______

How can I add space in-between those elements to archive a look like this (arrows are spaces), so that the inputs are at the same point:

Title:  ------------> _________
Description: ---> _________

Comment: Put them in some sort of grid layout. Examples of layout libraries and custom solutions abound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the existing markup (requires a fixed width for the label elements):

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label>Title</label>
<input><br>
<label>Description</label>
<input>
```

If you have a wrapper (container) element:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <label>Title</label>
  <input>
  <label>Description</label>
  <input>
</div>
```